# Email Invoice Details from Invoice Workflow in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, I have a workflow configured to "Send Email" once Invoice status is marked "Paid". However, in the Email Template, it does not appear I have access to fields from the Invoice Details entity. How can I include the line items from the Invoice (via Invoice Details)?

I've also tried with Order record, but I also cannot insert fields from the Sales Order Details entity.

I do not want to create a custom workflow plugin. Do I have any other options? If I must create a custom workflow plugin, is there an example of where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box email templates aren't designed to handle the relationship between a header record and the line items (Opportunity, Quote, Order, & Invoice).

If you are looking to generate the email from a workflow, custom code if probably your only option. The [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004) would be the best place to start. It contains lots of examples and great documentation.

Also out of the box, CRM 2011 doesn't appear to let you mail merge the Invoice entity, but I believe C360's [Documents Pack](http://www.c360.com/DocumentsPack.aspx) will let you do this. It would be a manual process and it is a paid product but it allow you to avoid writing code.

Comment: While not a solution, appears the exact solution desired does not exist. Thanks for confirming.